# Why ItemCommand isn't called if I moved the `DataBind` for a server control from `Page_Load` to `Page_PreRender`

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why `ItemCommand` isn't called if I moved the `DataBind` for a server control from `Page_Load` to `Page_PreRender`?

Any help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen on the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), `PreRender` occurs *after* control events have fired.

This includes the `ItemCommand` event.

You need to bind at a point in the page life cycle *before* the control events fire.